# Перенос кода из Turbo C в Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Вообще код запустился но на "Turbo C 3", а на "Visual studio 2010 Express" не захотел.
Как исправить ошибки: в маленьком окошке и в самой VS2010 [на картинке](http://i30.fastpic.ru/big/2011/0928/1e/20632e2df551596a06159754f8af0b1e.jpg).

```
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main (void)
{
float radius;
double surface, volum;
puts("Vvedite radius");
scanf("%f",&radius);
surface=(float)4.0*3.1415*pow(radius, 2.0);
volum=(float)4.0/3.0*3.1415*pow(radius, 3.0);
printf(
"\tRadius ravem %10.2f\n"
"\tPloshad ravna %10.2f\n"
"\tObiem raven %10.2f\n"
, radius, surface, volum);
getch();
}
```

Comment: Какие ошибки выдает под студией?

Comment: Я картинку дал.

Comment: Мысли две: создайте простое консольное приложение, создайте приложение в папке, в пути к которой не будет не латинских символов.

Comment: Добавьте новый скриншот

Answer (score 3):

`conio.h` - нестандартный хэдер, его лучше не использовать, т.к. он есть по-умолчанию только в Borland С++. Соответственно, надо удалить из кода вызов `getch()`. А чтобы окошко не закрывалось после завершения программы можно запускать через `Ctrl + F5`.

**UPD:** посмотрел вашу картинку, еще есть следующие проблемы:

1. Надо добавить `#include "stdafx.h"` или отключить precompiled headers в настройках проекта.
2. Ошибка с `pow` возникает из-за того, что в C++ есть несколько версий функции `pow`, например, `float pow(float, float)` и `double pow(double, double)`. В вашем случае один из аргументов имеет тип `float`, а второй `double`, поэтому компилятор не знает, какую версию выбрать. Можно вызвать вот так - `pow(radius, 2.0f)` - так вы покажите, что 2.0 имеет тип `float` (по умолчанию `double`). Хотя похоже, что вы пишете на C, а там такой проблемы нет в отличии от C++ - просто в настройках проекта укажите, что программа на C.

Comment: conio.h в Visual Studio есть точно.

Comment: Возможно, но это не отменяет его нестандартности. В gcc его нет, например.

Comment: спасибо вы код оставил исходный но вы были правы насчет "pow(radius, 2.0f)"

Answer (score 2):

Если код на С++, то первая проблема - библиотека `conio.h`, она идет только с турбо С++. Саму функцию `main` - описать как возвращающую `int` (просто стандарт). `getch()` - из `conio.h`, соответственно его "изъять", использовать `getchar()` - если это необходимо. Вот код со всеми исправлениями:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
float radius;
double surface, volum;
puts("Vvedite radius");
scanf("%f",&radius);
surface=(float)4.0*3.1415*pow(radius, 2.0);
volum=(float)4.0/3.0*3.1415*pow(radius, 3.0);
printf(
"\tRadius ravem %10.2f\n"
"\tPloshad ravna %10.2f\n"
"\tObiem raven %10.2f\n"
, radius, surface, volum);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,но маленькое окно с ошибкой все еще вылезает при запуске